# What's the word used to describe an "individual-like" entity?

Tags: single-word-requests

Most people consider 'individual' to be roughly synonymous with 'person.' Specifically, they would not consider an organization an 'individual.'

However, it may be said that organizations possess beliefs, desires, responsibilities, etc. much in the same way that people do.

Is there a word that encompasses this trait of being "like an individual," and thus includes humans, organizations, etc.?

Comment: @Bread "*Like* a human is not equal to human." Dude. No shit. How is this relevant?

Comment: @Bread Umm... ok. I've seen your comment. I also read the answer with 'entity.' It does work for me. I just didn't really think of that word when I was asking the question, as it sort of had the connotation of something slightly more general, but when I thought about it hard enough, no example that I didn't want came to mind.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You used [Entity](http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/entity.html) in your question.  I think it's the best term for what you describe.
*A person, partnership, organization, or business that has a legal and separately identifiable existence.*

http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/entity.html

Comment: ... but neither the partnership, the organization nor the business can, rightly, be called an 'individual'. Only the _person_ can be so designated.

Comment: @Nigel J.  I'm not sure what you mean.  I did not suggest 'individual'.  I suggested 'entity'.

Answer (score 1):

The word **organism** is used with this broadened sense (though it is not of course the primary sense):

> *organism* noun ...
>
> 1.2 A system or organization consisting of interdependent parts, compared to a living being.
>
> *the Church is a divinely constituted organism*

{[ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/organism)}